# Choosing appropriate statistical tests

Tags: spss, inference, descriptive-statistics, biostatistics, mutual-information

I am trying to run stats on medical treatment data and would like your guys and girls help

**Goal: Comparing two trends of annual percentages for statistical significance. Is one decreasing due to the other one increased, vice versa.**

More detail: Trying to see whether the use of treatment P (TP) is decreasing ever since treatment B (TB) has been introduced in the past 10 years as an annual percentage of total patients diagnosed. Repeating this for multiple diagnoses & treatments.

Population:

Patients diagnosed with disease A or disease B, and either can be treated with TP or TB. We think TB should be overtaking TP because it's more convenient and can be done at home, while TP is a pain in the ass treatment.

We have annual data on disease C which can be used as a control (i think?), because it can't be treated with TB

We have annual data on treatment X, which can also be used as a control(i think?) because it can be used for any of the diseases

We have annual data on total # of patients diagnosed with A, B; and we have total # of patients diagnosed with A, B, that are receiving TP or TB in every year. We can also split it up into receiving ONLY TP or ONLY TB.

Confounders:

Overall volume of treatments has been going up as more patients come, so how would we attribute the rise in TP or TB to overall volume rise vs rise in the use of the treatment (possible solutions: calculating the treatments as a % of all patients, that way the percentage wouldn't be affected by the rising volume).

**Questions:
1) Is reporting a % (treated with TB or TP / total diagnosed) sufficient for accounting for the overall rise in volume of patients diagnosed & treated?
2) What statistical analyses should I do to be able to report on the changes in TP vs TB for each disease?
3) How do I set up the control, and then compare the experimental group to the control?
4) Is there a value to using the ONLY TP or ONLY TB data? In other words does it matter if we report:
for disease A, 500 patients received TP and 200 received TB
versus
for disease A, 400 patients received ONLY TP and not TB, and 100 received ONLY TB and not TP**

Comment: All the text has to be collapsed into: what group is each patient in?, what are the demographic & patient treatment histories (y/n) for each patient, etc.   Basically, everything has to be collapsed down to a multiway table, where each patient falls into one cell of the table.  Then look at polytomous logistic regression.

Comment: The thing is I don't have individual patient data, the data essentially looks like this: 2010 - 300 patients got TP, 200 got TB; 2011 - 350 patients got TP, 250 got TB; etc.

Comment: Actually, I can go back and recreate data points for each patient in excel. However, does do I have to use binary data (Y/N) for every treatment? Or can I assign categories like TB, TP?  Finally, do my data points have to be mutually exclusive? i.e. 1) (Count if TB NOT TP) vs (Count if TP NOT TB) or can they be 2) (Count if TB) vs (Count if TP)

Comment: No, don't re-create individual data.  It may be that the only thing you can do with aggregate count data (numbers of patients in categories) is to run a multiway contingency table with a chi-squared test.   This is called "qualitative" data analysis is very popular in psychometrics.  So look at a table setup and questions/hypotheses posited by the examples you study.   If you had a lot of count data, then a modeling technique called log-linear regression (which uses count data) could be used.  It could be possible to run Poisson regression, but you don't have enough data.

Comment: You can always run tests of two (independent) proportions p1 and p2, where you have the number of failures or successes and the total denominator number in each group.  Then start moving through all possible pairs of 2-proportion tests to fill gaps in hypothesis.   With multiple tests (p-values) you will run into the "multiple testing problem" which according to the Bonferroni adjustment method requires that any of the p-values ($P$) from $k$ tests need to be lower than $\alpha^* = P/k$.  The Bonf simply transforms the default $\alpha=0.05$ into $\alpha^*$.